# How come replacing char[] with IntPtr or StringBuilder in a DllImport return value causes my program to no longer find the correct entry point?

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop, pinvoke

**EDIT: I just realized this is defined as a MACRO, not a function.  How the heck would I import a macro from a DLL to C#? (this may have to be a new question).**

This is related to a question I just asked:

> [How Do I Properly Return A Char From An Unmanaged Dll To C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757448/how-do-i-properly-return-a-char-from-an-unmanaged-dll-to-c)

Some of the answers suggested I change the function signature to IntPtr or StringBuilder. I also saw these solutions on a few sites in my googling, most notably [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1378860.php). (There were others, but I don't have time to hunt down the links).

Function signature:

```
[DllImport("api.dll")]       
internal static extern char[] errMessage(int err);
```

If I change the return type, my call throws the following exception:

> "Unable to find an entry point named 'errMessage' in DLL"

I can't imagine people would suggest this if it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there something missing? Sad to say, but my C/C++ skills are terrible, so I could be missing something really simple. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Function signature from documentation:

```
char * errMessage(int err);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated to reflect importing a macro:

> **You can't.**

Now, what you can do is look at what the macro does, then implement that with P/Invoke. The below advice holds for that as well.

---

When working with Platform Invoke (P/Invoke) it is best to be as explicit as possible:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    private static string DllName = @"api.dll";

    // This uses 'string' assuming you do not have to free the memory.
    [DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "errMessage",
         CharSet = YourCharacterSet,              // CharSet.Ansi? .Unicode?
         CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention // .StdCall? .Cdecl?
    )]
    public static string errMessage(int errorCode);
}
```

Moreover, it is best to provide a managed entry-point that makes the method more ".Net". This is where you would ensure that Caller allocated memory gets held the appropriate amount of time (you may have to implement a [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx)) or that other hand-waving gets handled.

Assuming `errMessage` returns a string we aren't responsible for deallocating:

```
public static class ManagedMethods
{
    public static string ErrorMessage(ErrorCode errorCode)
    {
        return NativeMethods.errMessage((int)errorCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a C++/CLI wrapper. It is an amazingly easy and powerful way to bridge the gap between C# and unmanaged (old) C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your C/C++ method to return a pointer, AFAIK I have not seen a DllImport returning back an array of characters from a function. I would suggest you change around your API code within the function errMessage, perhaps instead of returning back char[], you could return back a pointer to char in your api.dll library...i.e.

void errMessage(int err, char *ptr);

On second note...are you using this to return back a standard Win API error code, there is a Marshal.Win32Error class that would do just the job for you?
What do you think?
Tom.

Comment: I am trying to write a C# wrapper for a third party API. I've edited the post above to show exactly what I am trying to call. This method takes an int and returns their specific error messages.  A lot of their methods have char * as the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the calling convention is not stdcall (which is the default one used by DllImport).
C/C++ use the CDECL calling convention if not declared otherwise. So you have to add this calling convention to the DllImport call.