# How do I properly return a char * from an Unmanaged DLL written in C to VB .net?

Tags: .net, c, vb.net, interop, unmanaged

How do I properly return a char * from an Unmanaged DLL to VB .net and use it as a string in VB?
From [a similar post for C# and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757448/how-do-i-properly-return-a-char-from-an-unmanaged-dll-to-c) it appears that the c# syntax to do such a  thing is

```
[DllImport("api.dll")]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
internal static extern string errMessage(int err);
...
string message = errMessage(err);
```

Does VB .net have a corresponding syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DllImport("Project1.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Function agmemwrite(graph As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> String
End Function
```