# DllImport and char Marshaling

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I'm newbie at C# and Marshaling. I need to use my C func in C#, but i have an incorrect return value from C func (or I don't know how to convert it to correct answer).

C source:

```
#include "main.h"

char *Ololo(char *arg, int &n3)
{
    char *szRet;
    szRet=(char*)malloc(strlen(arg)+1);
    strcpy(szRet,arg);
    n3 = strlen(szRet);
    return szRet;
}
```

C header:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char *Ololo(char *arg, int &n3);
```

C# source:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"F:\Projects\service\dll\testDLL2.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr Ololo([In] char[] arg, ref Int32 n3);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string n1 = "ololo";
        char[] chars = new char[n1.Length];
        chars = n1.ToCharArray();
        Int32 n3 = 0;
        IntPtr result;
        result = Ololo(chars, ref n3);
        string n4 = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(result,n3);
        Console.WriteLine(n4);
    }
}
```

I've got return something like "o?? ?"

Sorry for bad English

----------------------Solved-----------------------

```
class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"F:\Projects\service\dll\testDLL2.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr Ololo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string arg, ref Int32 n3);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string n1 = "ololo";
            Int32 n3 = 0;
            int n2 = n1.Length;
            IntPtr result;
            result = Ololo(n1, ref n3);
            string n4 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result, n3);
            Console.WriteLine(n4);
        }
    }
```

That works fine. In n3 i ve got 5 and in n4 ololo! Thank s for quick answers!

Comment: btw 'int &n3' is not C, its C++ notation.

Comment: You haven't solved anything, the code leaks the memory for the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Char * marshalling in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808581/char-marshalling-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Hans Passant There is one difference: On your link func which return char * was rewrited to void func. In my question the first was how to catch return(char *). And if there is memory leak, how to free return(char*) in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public static extern IntPtr Ololo([In] char[] arg, ref Int32 n3);`

`IntPtr` is the wrong return type, as essentially you want to return the string, not a pointer to the string.  In C you can use a pointer to your string by using `char*`, the equivalent in .NET would be to use use this: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string`. This should marshall the `char*`  to a `string` correctly.

`IntPtr` represents a pointer type, which to get your actual string is useless.

Also looks like you should be taking a `StringBuilder` into your Marshalled function, and not a `char[]`.  Then at least you should be getting the correct string to your C function.

Comment: I think `IntPtr` is correct because `n3` returns me 1 and int `IntPtr` I`ve got first letter (o). But why I have `n3` = 1? I think it need`s to be 5. Because of that I think `[In] char[] arg` is incorrect. But what is correct?

Comment: @Treno1 your function in .NET will never give you the entire string back if you return `IntPtr`.

Comment: System.AccessViolationException if I try to `public static extern StringBuilder Ololo(string arg, ref Int32 n3);` and `StringBuilder n5 = Ololo(n1, ref n3);`

Answer (score 0):

The marshaller does not NULL terminate `char` arrays for funsies. It will do it because you told it to- *if* you told it to. You are fortunate because a `char` in .NET is UTF-16, and this is 16 bits wide- and the second byte will be zero because that is `'o'` in UTF-16, thus giving a strlen of 1. The actual effort to pass in a managed string as a null-terminated C string is a tad higher than you seem to appreciate. So let the marshaller do all the work- it already knows how to do this job.

```
public static extern [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Ololo(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string arg,
    ref int n3
);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string n1 = "ololo";
    Int32 n3 = 0;
    string n4 = Ololo(chars, ref n3);
    Console.WriteLine(n4);
}
```

Comment: VS 2010 think that `public static extern [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Ololo` is incorrect because of `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] cannot be in declaration of class , structure or interface`.

Comment: It isn't. You must have failed to copy the DLLImport attribute over, or placed the declaration in the wrong place.