# Invoke a C DLL function to marshal a string from a type defined char

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, dllimport

This is my first attempt at creating a C# wrapper to a C lib. The SDK is 3rd party and outside my control:

sdk_defines.h

```
#ifndef SDK_CHAR_T
#define SDK_CHAR_T
typedef char sdk_char_t;
#endif /* SDK_CHAR_T */

#ifndef SDK_CSTR_T
#define SDK_CSTR_T
typedef const sdk_char_t*  sdk_cstr_t;
#endif /* SDK_CSTR_T */
```

sdk.h

```
sdk_cstr_t SDK_API
sdk_get_version(void);
```

My C# wrapper:

```
[DllImport("sdk.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern string sdk_get_version();
```

Any call to sdk_get_version causes a crash, no exception. I have a feeling it's the return type, but how do I properly marshal it in C#?

Comment: does it work if you add [return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] between the [DllImport] and private static extern ... ?

Comment: How is SDK_API defined?

Comment: removed my answer, go for Davids solution. i'm not entirely sure and David seems to be :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return as `string`, then the marshaller will call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer that is returned. I expect that's what's happening to you and is why your code fails. Looking at that API it seems most likely that the pointer that is returned points to a string literal in the DLL, certainly not something allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

So, you are going to need to return that as an `IntPtr` and then convert to string using `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

So you need it like this:

```
[DllImport("sdk.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr sdk_get_version();

....

IntPtr ptr = sdk_get_version();
string version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

Before you go much further you need to work out what `SDK_API` is. Is it `stdcall` or is it `cdecl`? It makes no difference for this no-parameter function, but before long you'll be passing parameters, and you'll need to know.

Comment: thx for the corrections +1 for being smarter (and cool enough to not throw me on -1 :))

Comment: @bas No probs at all. Read Jared's answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370079/pinvoke-for-c-function-that-returns-char