# What type to PInvoke for a char**

Tags: c#

Consider the following C function:

```
void get_lib_version(const char **ver_string);
```

How do I marshall this correctly with PInvoke? The documentation says it returns a pointer to a static string. I thought this would do it:

```
[DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int get_lib_version(StringBuilder version);
```

but all I get is gibberish.

Comment: char** is an array of strings, so perhaps StringBuilder [], or string [].

Comment: Have you tried `ref StringBuilder version`? That *might* work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns a brand new C-string.  The pinvoke marshaller always makes sure that the memory required to store a string that's returned by native code is released again.  This will not come to a good end, surely the caller of this function is not supposed to release it.  The *const* keyword is a strong hint that the native code will return a pointer to a string literal that's not allocated on the heap.  Trying to release such a pointer will crash your program on later Windows versions, the kind that have a strict heap implementation (after XP).

You have to help to stop the marshaller from doing this.  This requires you to declare the argument as a raw pointer, not a string:

```
  [DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern int get_lib_version(out IntPtr version);
```

And you have to make the extra step to convert the pointer to a string:

```
  public string GetLibraryVersion() {
      IntPtr strptr;
      get_lib_version(out strptr);
      return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strptr);
  }
```

Write a little test program to verify this assumption.  Call GetLibraryVersion() a billion times.  If the memory usage doesn't explode then you're good.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370519/1006010), when you marshal something as `string`, PInvoke makes all sorts of assumptions about how it's supposed to get freed. Notice that this is a `const char *`; it's a constant string somewhere. It *never* needs to be deallocated!

Apparently the way to deal with this is

1. Marshall as `IntPtr`.
2. Use `Marshall.PtrToStringAnsi()` to copy the result into a C# string.

I managed to get this to work correctly:

```
[DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int get_lib_version(ref IntPtr version);

public static string GetLibVersion()
{
  var ptrVersion = IntPtr.Zero;
  get_lib_version(ref ptrVersion);
  var version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrVersion);
  return version;
}
```