# Dllimport char* [] from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

How can I using Dllimport by C# to get string array from C library

```
int GetClasses (int *NumberofClasses, char *ClassNames[], int arrayLength)
```

I have try StringBuilder[] and many of MarshalAsAttributes to receive ClassNames but still not work and cause memory violation

I have only explanation of this C method is showing below.

```
int GetClasses(int * NumberofClasses, char * ClassNames[], int arrayLength)

This function will get the total number of unique classes and each unique class name.

Parameters:
NumberofClasses: Total number of unique classes.
ClassNames: Array of allocated char * to return class names.
arrayLength: Length of passed ClassNames array. If the result exceeds this array length, this function will fail with an error code.

Returns: Zero for success. Non-zero for error
```

And my declaration is

```
[DllImport(@".\library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern Int16 GetClasses(ref UInt16 NumberofClasses, StringBuilder[]  ClassNames, UInt16 arrayLength);
```

I have pass

NumberofClasses=16,

ClassNames= StringBuilder[16] with 256 capacity of each

arrayLength=16

to this call

Comment: You neeed to know the excact contract assumed by the function. Probably the caller needs to pass an array of `arrayLength` `char*` pointers. Will the function allocate memory for the individual strings and put the pointers into the array? If yes: how exactly does the C library allocate the memory? The caller might have to free this memory again. Here is a similayr question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219625/what-type-to-pinvoke-for-a-char

Comment: Show an example of how is your C code is written.

Comment: I don't have the C library source code. The library is provided by supplier and can't get any more information from supplier.

Comment: What made you think int maps to Int16? Anyway the easiest way to proceed here is to write some C code that calls it successfully. And then learn from that.

Comment: Because the supplier provided some C# sample code before. In the sample int is mapped  to Int16 and the call runs successfully.

Comment: Well Int16 is wrong, it should be int which is a 32 bit integer. I still feel that getting this working with C code would clear things up. Surely the supplier has examples of that. You also didn't show your code to make the call. Who knows if that was done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the success call by modify the declaration of parameter type.

```
[DllImport(@".\library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern Int16 GetClasses(ref UInt16 NumberofClasses, [In][Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] string[] ClassNames, UInt16 arrayLength);
```

And allocate a string array to parameter ClassNames

```
string[] names = new string[NumberOfClasses];

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = new string(new char[256]);
}
```

Comment: Please add this to your question by editing it instead of posting it as answers (which it is not).